# Embeddable GraphDBs?

Tags: nosql, embedded-database, neo4j, graph-databases

Could you recommend me GraphDB that can be embedded in one app process like Neo4j, but must be free for commercial usage and must supports C# or Java?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: See my answer regarding millions of records in Neo4j [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166092/neo4j-license-limitations/4166640#4166640).

Comment: @nawroth, Sorry! originaly my question was not correct;)

Comment: you probably realized this in the meantime, but your question is imprecise concerning the term _commercial_: Neo4J is absolutely free for commercial usage, as long as your software is open source and distributed under the AGPLv3 as well, just like Neo4J itself (see my [edit of the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4184463/revisions) for more on this). Presumably you meant _free for a closed source project_ though? This would indeed limit your options respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neo4j's open-source version doesn't limit the size of database.

**Edit:**

[Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/)'s open-source version is licensed under [AGPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html), so you can't use it with closed source software products; your first *unsupported instance of [Neo Basic Server](http://neotechnology.com/product-overview) is free of charge* though, so if you neither need commercial support nor the full feature set you are good to go for a closed source project as well.

But, good news for you: [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/) is a java embeddable, fast, transactional (ACID), scalable, lightweight graph-document database, also supports SQL. And it's licensed under [Apache 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html), so OrientDB is free for any use.

Comment: Thank you for answer! i mean "free" for commercial projects;) Neo4j is not free like most of popular NoSQL databases. P.S. I'll correct my question;)

Comment: To be correct: Neo4j is dual licensed. On the opensource side it uses AGPL and there are commercial licenses. There is even a free commerical license.

Comment: Neo4j is GPL, not AGPL anymore. For details, see http://www.neo4j.org/learn/licensing

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest OrientDB, but you can find more choices here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database.

Answer (score 2):

As Rustam suggested look at OrientDB.  It is under Apache 2.0 licensing and even the support they provide (if you want) is reasonably priced.

Also for the C# option look at this [repository](https://github.com/ahzf/repositories).  I haven't looked at the code or used it yet, but it has .NET interfaces for:

1. BluePrints
2. Rexster
3. Pipes

These utilities can be used to connect with multiple Graph Databases including neo4j and OrientDB.  For more information also look at [TikerPop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into Titan/CassandraEmbedded with the new in-memory cache layer in Titan 0.4.1. http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/11/24/boutique-graph-data-with-titan/