# Neo4j license limitations?

Tags: licensing, neo4j

Please tell me, are there limitations of maximum records per node within Basic license? For example i can store only max 10M records per Basic license? Or record count is unlimited by Basic license?

Thank you!

Comment: It is asking about the licensing of the third part product that is liable to change and be inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no size limitations on any version. There once was, and that information is still floating around ...

For more information, ask someone [here](http://neotechnology.com/contact).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the community edition in the same way that you would use MySQL.

From http://www.neotechnology.com/price-list/

> If you don’t need any of the reliability features in the Advanced or Enterprise editions, then you’re free to use the Community edition of Neo4j Server under a GPL license – which means you can use it anywhere you would use something like MySQL. Used in this way, only changes you make to the Neo4j software itself should be open-sourced and shared with the community.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Neo4j community is as good as Neo4j enterprise edition (w.r.t features), only difference you cannot use it in closed source applications http://neotechnology.com/price-list

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a section on Neo4j.org, see http://www.neo4j.org/learn/licensing